# Добавление свойств товара к заказу

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Добрый день! Есть таблицы `Users`, которая содержит пользователей, `Item`, которая содержит товары, `Orders`, которая содержит заказы и многие ко многим `Items_orders` с количеством товара. На странице пользователь может задать своё количество некоторых безделушек входящих в товар, сделать заказ, после чего и будет рассчитываться стоимость товара. Вопрос: как правильно это организовать? Какие таблицы, поля еще необходимо добавить? Спасибо!

[image]

**UPD:** по замечанию **@ua6xh** в 1ом комментарии добавлена таблица `Items_time`:

[image]

Comment: А вы смотрели как организовано оформление заказа в интернет магазинах? Например у юлмарта и ситилинка хранятся мои заказы годовалой давности и в этих заказах указаны цены которые были тогда, а в данный момент либо эти цены изменились, либо продукт уже снят с продажи. Т.е. скорее всего есть таблица items_ord (это товары и их цены на момент покупки), а order_item не связанны с таблицей items на прямую, записи из таблицы items "клонируются" в таблицу items_ord. Записи плодятся конечно, но как по другому это организовать - пока не знаю. Может кто раскроет свет на этот вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо, хорошее замечание